# How properly to load resource in designer view?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.7.2

I have an app with resource files, let's say it has a background image and icon that I would like to use on all my app forms. On runtime, everything works perfectly and forms load the background picture and icon with no problem. However, if I open the form in designer I get this:

> The type 'app.Properties.Resources' has no property 'my_icon' / 'my_background'.

Here's the code:

```cs
this.Icon = global::app.Properties.Resources.my_icon;
this.BackgroundImage = global::app.Properties.Resources.my_background;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should post your code, it's not clear what you're doing. `System.ComponentModel` use the [ComponentResourceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.componentresourcemanager) class to add resources at design-time. See also the [ISupportInitialize Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize)

Comment: its no another code except these 2 lines, its a poc prj so nothing else just load icon from resources file and set background from the same, may add a whole project if needed but its so simple to recreate.

Comment: Whatever you have post it, those two lines on their own don't make much sense. Give it context (and explain why you are using `global::` there). You also need to specify the .Net version in use.  -- See the linked documentation to load Resources at design-time. If you're building a Template, then say that explicitly and describe its use-case.

Comment: global because resource file not linked to form. 
.Net 4.7.2 then I set a standard icon let say via browse all loads fine, but i want to load it from my resx file and for some reason cant do it. :( this case seems very specific, we need a guru there who understand how this part is working, if these lines don't tell nothing then sorry :) I don't think you will find an answer :)

Comment: When you add a `.resx` file to your Project, it creates an internal class named after the Resource object. You can replace / add to the Designer.cs file, e.g., `this.Icon = global::[Namespace].[RESX Name].[Icon Name]; `. So, if the `.resx` file is named, e.g., `MoreIcons.resx` and it contains an icon named `my_icon` you have: `this.Icon = global::[Namespace].MoreIcons.my_icon;`.  Of course, replace `[Namespace]` with the actual namespace of the Project that uses these resources.

Comment: It's much simple if you build a satellite `dll` that contains extra resource and exposes public static methods that allow to retrieve these objects from anywhere in a Solution. So, if you need to replace all Icons in a Solution, you just change the Icon in the satellite `dll` and just recompile that. -- Design-time linking may be more complex, though.

Comment: At run-time, you can use the `System.Resources..ResourceManager` class to fetch a resource by name. Using the same `.resx` file, e.g., `ResourceManager^ rm = gcnew ResourceManager("[Namespace].MoreIcons", GetType()->Assembly); this->Icon = safe_cast<System::Drawing::Icon^>(rm->GetObject(L"my_icon"));`

Comment: Jimi thanks for you keep trying but that exactly that did already, if you look carefully to my provided 2 lines they are about that you are saying namespace = [app], Properties is standard resource manager and Resources is my resx file. and that lines at runtime working perfect! No problems, problems they are not working on design time, and that is my question about.

Comment: That's not what I wrote. I didn't mention `Properties` anywhere and I don't see how that could be useful here. Following your example, it should be `this.Icon = global::app.[RESX File Name].my_icon;`, assuming `app`  is the `namespace` of your application. I also assume your `.resx` file **is not** named `Resources`. As described, you can add that line of code to the `Designer.cs` file and it will work at design-time.

Comment: If all this doesn't apply, then you have done something weird, maybe changed some internal classes. That's why I asked you to post a clear description of what you have (and what you have actually done), in relation to this resource file. If you have simply added a `.resx` file to the Project, `Properties` doesn't know anything about it. -- I posted a comment in the wrong language. Sorry for that, I was writing in that form...

Comment: on runtime all working, so references a set correctly, nothing messy have been try to start from scratch - same result, perhaps bug of vs2019 :(

Comment: Well, did you try to do as I described or not? Give it a shot.

Comment: seems issue with my VS, thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

Based on my test, you could put your code in Form1.Designer.cs-> InitializeComponent Method.

Code:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            // Load the resource file in designer view
            this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.my_background;
            this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
            this.Icon = Properties.Resources.my_icon; 
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
     
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(731, 406);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
```

After rebuild the project, you can load the resource in designer view.

[image]

Comment: thanks, in my case its not working for some reason. However on dot walking its able to trace resource properly, perhaps something messy with settings of my VS2019, could you please mentioned that version you have?

Comment: @Gorodeckij Dimitrij, I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Version 16.10.0.